# How can I mount an external HDD to Docker ElasticSearch - error is NoSuchFileException

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch in a docker container, and trying to mount the ES data to an external drive. I tried what I thought was an obvious approach, yet I am getting a path existence error in the ES container - *not* the typical permissions error I've seen elsewhere in SO.

```
(base) peter@Peters-MBP14 ~ % docker run --name es01-t7v --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -v /Volumes/T7/pdr/dom-2.2.1/es-data-01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.8.2

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.asIOException(UnixException.java:115)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:477)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:481)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3767)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.isDirEmpty(AutoConfigureNode.java:1144)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.cli.AutoConfigureNode.execute(AutoConfigureNode.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.autoConfigureSecurity(ServerCli.java:165)
    at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.execute(ServerCli.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
    at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
```

But when I change the mount path to my primary drive (not my external drive), it starts fine:
`docker run --name es01-t7v2 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -v /Users/peter/es-test-mnt1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data -it docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.8.2`

Although the error doesn't suggest this, I checked permissions on the external drive folder and it seems OK.

```
(base) peter@Peters-MBP14 ~ % ls -al /Volumes/T7/pdr/dom-2.2.1/es-data-01
total 512
drwxrwxrwx  1 peter  staff  131072 Jul 19 19:18 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 peter  staff  131072 Jul 19 17:30 ..
```

I also tried a symlink from local HD to external HD, and got a different error (beyond the scope of this SO question)

Comment: How do those permissions compare to your primary drive `/Users/peter/es-test-mnt1`?

Comment: Initially it was `drwxr-xr-x`, but now that I checked again it is `drwxrwxr-x@`. But  I thought `drwxrwxrwx` was most permissive of all?

Comment: What about user/group. for each of those folders?

Comment: Ah ha, that's it! Amazing, thanks! For es-test-mnt1 it's `peter  staff`; for the HDD it's `_unknown _unknown`.  I guess I need to `chown -R peter:staff` ? (Although now I wonder why I, but not Docker, can R/W to it if it's _unknown)

Comment: Although I do not understand why the user/group is different if I sudo or not: https://pastebin.com/ChdBLxHv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoSuchFileException` means that the user probably doesn't have access to the folder.

You need to make sure that the user/group and their permissions on `/Volumes/T7/pdr/dom-2.2.1/es-data-01` are the same as for `/Users/peter/es-test-mnt1`.

Comment: sudo chown -R peter:staff /Volumes/T7/pdr/dom-2.2.1/es-data-01 ran without error but the user/group did not update when I checked using` sudo ls -AFleO`. I am marking my initial question as answered because what I'm encountering now is probably something else.